# Maximum Bluetooth LE devices near each other

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, interference

I am planning to put 100+ Ruuvitag beacons(Bluetooth LE tranmistters) in a ~120m2 area. There will be approximately 1 meter distance between devices. I need to get their advertisements at once(each beacon will send data every X minutes) using `Raspberry Pi Zero`.

Something like this:
[image]

1. Any idea how many Bluetooth LE devices can transmit advertisements at once without interefering with each other?
2. How many advertisements do you think a single receiver could receive at once without problems?

Comment: Please define "at once". If you mean literally simultaneous (<~10µS), the answer is 3, because BLE allocates 3 channels for advertisements. Note that if you can't control channels on your chosen device, the answer is likely 1.

Comment: Well, it means that each beacon will send data every 2 mins for exple

Comment: I'm specifically asking about the "at once" requirement. Do you mean that the advertisers will all transmit at the same time, or that the scanner simply needs to "pick up" no less than one advertisement from each advertiser every 2 minutes?

Comment: All transmitters will broadcast data at the same time because will use same time period between broadcasts. The receiver will listen continiously for these broadcasts

Comment: Anecdotally, I've worked with a scanner and many broadcasters in range, all sharing the 'same' period of 500ms (within the tolerance of a +-20ppm 32kHz crystal), but all of which had different (even slightly different) start times. In this case, I've had no trouble receiving most advertisements from roughly 500 devices advertising every period. In a theoretical world where advertisements happen at the same time, then the answer is 1, unless you control the transmitters and choose different advertisement channels, in which case it is 3.

Comment: So, you are saying that although the same period, in reality there will be slight differences between start times and thus 100 devices should not have issues transmitting "at the same time"?

Comment: Yes, this has been my experience. Your results may vary.